# Firefox msg, need to be avoid

Tags: php

**To display this page, Firefox must send information that will repeat any action (such as a search or order confirmation) that was performed earlier.**

I am getting this firefox error. Though I am unsetting all variables at end of page using `<?php unset[$_POST] ?>`.. But if I update some record or update page again using this. Than I got above error.

Comment: that's not an error, it's just a warning that the browser displays when you try to submit a page that you reached after a form was submitted using POST.. I don't think you can avoid it since it's some kind of a security measure

Comment: This is not an error. Firefox suggest you that you made a POST request and so, refreshing the page (F5), you'll send the data again.

Answer (score 4):

After processing the request you should made a redirection to the same page to avoid such type of warning.

Saying OK to the warning message above will resubmit your form again and the PHP processing will be repeated. This should be avoided otherwise your database will have duplicated records if there is an INSERT query is getting processed.

```
header('location:http://www.example.com/currentpage');
die();
```

EDIT

You should do it something like below:-

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
   //filter the data and validate user input
   //do some stuff
   /* Redirect users back to same url instead of refreshing page with javascript*/
     header('location:http://www.example.com/currentpage');
     die();
}
```

Comment: Means where should I implement this. I mean first time I am submitting form using simple save button button but second time when I actually get this warning is when I try to refresh page using java script.. Please give me some more hint with this issue.

Comment: @RahulSingh: Answer updated, I hope you should get an Idea how it should be done